# Unable to use several media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It seems like CSS only recognizes the first media query. Whenever I change the screen size to see different changes it only "falls into" the first media query or the general CSS code.

I have tried moving the media queries above and below the working query but it does not change anything. In the queries I change several colors to black so that I could test if they actually worked, but it didn't change anything.

This is an example of my media query layout.

```
*** REST OF CSS FILE UP HERE ***

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

I have two of the top media query, because one of them is for the normal navbar, and the other is for the responsive navbar (after a button has been clicked).

An example within the first media query:

```
.welcome {
    background: url(./images/welcome-mb.jpeg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.display-3 {
  font-size: 28pt;
}
.welcome-text {
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.tekstbokse {
  margin: auto;
}
.box-1 {
  background-position: bottom;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 275px;
}
.box-2 {
  background-position: bottom;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 350px;
  padding-bottom: 275px;
}
```

I expected the styling within each media query to be present for the corresponding screen size, but the styling is either the general CSS or from the first two media queries.

Comment: Would you be able to create working js fiddle with this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be over qualifying your media queries.

I would write these as:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .stuff: rule;
}
```

I favor max widths to prevent overlapping styles.

for example if you have

```
.element{
    width: 1000px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { 
    .element{
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

the page IS at least 600px so you'll have the media query overriding your standard styles.

max-width using the same css code would tell the page that once the width EXCEEDS 600px then this rule no longer applies and it defaults to your original class rules ignoring the media query altogether.